# Is it possible to get a Bob to move without killing him?

Tags: aleph-one, marathon

On levels that have Bobs in them, the Bobs frequently get stuck - jammed together in narrow hallways and such, blocking them. On levels such as [The Rose](http://marathon.bungie.org/spoiler/m1/5.shtml) (Marathon 1) where your mission is to keep as many from being killed as possible, it's kind of counterproductive to kill the Bobs to get them out of the way; but if they're blocking the door to an important comm terminal then sometimes there's no choice but to kill them.

Is there any way to 'prod' a Bob to move in the other direction without hurting or killing him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will sometimes move automatically but for the most part you have to shoot them. Don't feel bad, they are just B.O.B.s

Comment: Then again, there is the [vidmaster's oath](http://marathon.bungie.org/vidmaster/oathM2preview.html) :) Come to think of it, (at least on The Rose) I don't think the amount of BOBs killed affects the story any.

Comment: My only issue with the oath is with the autorun prohibition. Those levels can be huge.